# Java Code Coverage in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

I am using VSC for my Java project with maven help.
I would like to use a Code Coverage tool but I lost the directions in the many possibilities you have.
My goals are:

- run the Code Coverage goal with Maven;
- Display the test coverage in VSC with a plugin like [Coverage Gutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters)

Which Code Code coverage tool to use?
Can someone show me the right Maven plugin and the way to configure VSC?

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Prerequisites

- `Java Extension Pack` extension
- `Coverage Gutters` extension by ryanluker: To display test coverage generated
- `Live Preview` extension by Microsoft: To render HTML files in VSCode
- A maven project with some tests

## Steps

Add the `jacoco-maven-plugin` to your `pom.xml` file. This plugin will generate a report of your code coverage.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Generate the jacoco report by running the following command in your terminal:

```bash
mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test install jacoco:report
```

You should see a newly created file `target/site/jacoco/index.html`.

**NOTE: Each time you make a change to your tests, you need to rerun the above command to ensure that the code coverage report is accurate.**

### View detailed report

Open the HTML file (`target/site/jacoco/index.html`) and click on the magnify icon in the top right corner of VS Code. (Live Preview extension must be installed)
[image]

[image]

### Show inline coverage

Click on `Watch` in the bottom left toolbar of your VS Code. (Code Gutters extension must be installed)
[image]

Check out the class for which you wrote tests:
[image]

Green bars indicate that that code has been reached by your tests. Orange bars indicate a missed conditional check. Red bars indicate code that was not reached by your tests.

## References

- https://medium.com/@karlrombauts/setting-up-unit-testing-for-java-in-vs-code-with-maven-3dc75579122f
- https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

Comment: I'm finding the code coverage to be inaccurate.  The code gutter and coverage report are showing uncovered code, yet I have unit tests that do cover the code, verified by setting a breakpoint in the code and debugging the unit test(s).

Comment: @PoorInRichfield I have not faced this issue yet so I don't really know how to help you. If your problem persists, I recommend [creating an issue on the code gutters Github repository.](https://github.com/ryanluker/vscode-coverage-gutters/issues)

Comment: @PoorInRichfield Whenever you make a change to your tests, don't forget to regenerate the jacoco report manually using `mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test install jacoco:report
` otherwise the code coverage will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

For now, I don't think there is a way to show coverage inline for java code. This is not really an answer to your question but it may help. You can run tests (maybe create a task in vscode) then watch code coverage report in the browser.
For gradle it is:

```
./gradlew test jacocoTestReport
```

And then check the report at `build/TestCoverageReport/test/html/index.html`

You can do that also easily with maven.

Comment: if your here for coverage report check link coverage with maven >> https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html